# Need hint for integral question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, periodic-functions

Is it possible to show that 
$$
\int_a^b f(x)^2g(x) dx = 0
$$
if we know that 
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^bg(x)dx = 0 
$$

This is a step in a bit of a longer problem, but I got stuck at this point. In my eyes it would appear that since we are squaring $f(x)$ we will get a fully positive domain but I don't think that any arbitrary function that satisfies this property can be enough to make their product integral $0$. Any hints to show its truth or counterexample would be appreciated!

Comment: Nope, that definitely can't be true.  Pick almost any two functions---just avoid them being too "symmetric"---and you will have a counter-example.  A good place to start it to pick $ g(x) = x^2 - c $.  Find a number $ c $ so that $ \int_{-1}^{1}{g(x) dx } = 0 $, and this will be a useful function for getting a counterexample, because it's not odd.

Comment: Let $f=g=1$ for $0\le x<2$, $-2$ for $2\le x\le3$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture to give you some intuition that this is wrong:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be a broken line joing $(-4,0),(-2,2),(0,0),(1,-2),(4,0)$ and $f(x)=x$. Integrate on $[-4,4]$.